# loop to label multiple axes

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I need to run a loop to label 76 axes in a facetgrid plot I am creating. I am labelling the axes in a recurrent way -  after each 6 axes, I will start again from the label "Overall Score". If I were to do it manually, it would be like this:

```
axes[0].set_title("Overall Score")
axes[1].set_title("Business Ethics")
axes[2].set_title("Environment")
axes[3].set_title("Health & Safety")
axes[4].set_title("Labour")
axes[5].set_title("Management System")
axes[6].set_title("Overall Score")
....
axes[75].set_title("Management System")
```

But I do not have patience and I want to run a loop. So far I developed this but I cannot proceed.

```
for i in range(0,77):
    if i == 1:
       axes[i].set_title("Overall Score")
```

Suggestions?

Comment: not a python programmer but try adding the labels in a list and use mod function (I believe there is mod in python) to assign it to all the axes. Mod function should give you a reminder after the division, the divisor in your case should be 6. The reminder will be always between 0 and 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create list of all values by multiple by `13` and set in loop with `enumerate` for counter:

```
vals = ["Overall Score","Business Ethics","Environment",
        "Health & Safety","Labour","Management System"] * 13
for i, v in enumerate(vals):
    axes[i].set_title(v)
```

**Test**:

```
for i, v in enumerate(vals):
    print (i, v)
0 Overall Score
1 Business Ethics
2 Environment
3 Health & Safety
4 Labour
5 Management System
6 Overall Score
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
titles = (
    "Overall Score", "Business Ethics", "Environment",
    "Health & Safety", "Labour", "Management System"
)

for ax in axes:
    ax.set_title(titles[i % len(titles)])
```

Comment: much prettier solution!